# Please explain me how to use Disk Cache for storing images in simple language with a small example. I couldn't understand it from developer's site

Tags: android, caching

Please explain me how to use **Disk Cache** for storing images in simple language with a small  example in android. I couldn't understand it from developer's site. 
I am retrieving images from urls. So I need to store them in disk cache.I have used memory cache for now

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think you need to elaborate your question. Give a code example or anything else to make this question valid for SO.

Comment: I am retrieving images from urls. So I need to store them in disk cache.I have used memory cache for now.

Comment: please edit your question ..